# ¿Cómo pasar dos parametros por la url en Request::fullUrl() de laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo una url así: http://www.miweb.com/create?id=10&city=5 (Con dos parametros) y al utilizar esta función Request::fullUrl(), recibo solo el primer parametro de la url http://www.miweb.com/create?id=10 pero necesito recibir dos parametros, ejemplo: http://www.miweb.com/create?id=10&city=5

¿Cómo podría lograrlo?
gracias

Answer (score 0):

El método que recibe ese Request debería ser algo así

`function creare(Request $request)
{
$id = $request->id;
$city = $request->city;
}`

Comment: Sí, el problema es que la url queda así http://www.miweb.com/create?id=10 y no existe el parametro city en ella, por lo cual no puedo recibirla

Comment: El problema estaba en el controlador de logi, ya que sobrescribí unos métodos para hacer redirect, ya lo resolví agregando la ruta en el controlador. Gracias